# Como selecionar linhas parcialmente distintas?

Tags: mysql, query

Tenho uma tabela cuja coluna `reference` contém valores construídos da seguinte forma:

> Referência / Cor / Tamanho / Género

Exemplos:

```
JOHN/WHITE/52/MALE
JOHN/WHITE/51/FEMALE
JOHN/BLACK/52/MALE
JOHN/BLACK/51/FEMALE
JANE/BLACK/XL/MALE
JANE/PINK/L/FEMALE
578/WHITE/L/FEMALE
578/BLACK/L/FEMALE
```

Experimentei usar o [SUBSTR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>, mas a primeira porção da referência não é de tamanho fixo.

## Pergunta

Como posso selecionar os registos obtendo apenas um por cada referência encontrada?

Exemplo do resultado a obter com base nos exemplos em cima:

```
JOHN/WHITE/52/MALE
JANE/BLACK/XL/MALE
```

Comment: Você quer dizer um por nome? E tanto faz qual?

Comment: @bfavaretto Basicamente 1 por cada porção inicial da referência, não interessa qual, mas editei a pergunta para ilustrar que a porção inicial da referência é de valor variável.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se tanto faz qual item será selecionado para cada nome/referência, é possível conseguir esse resultado com [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```sql
SELECT * FROM refs
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(reference, '/', 1)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f1dec/1

O `SUBSTRING_INDEX` neste caso retorna um substring do valor de cada `reference` até a primeira ocorrência de `/`. O `GROUP BY` agrupa os resultados por esse valor.